# Export layout to Word

Tags: export

I would like to export the following layout to word:

```
m = 
  Import["https://earthnworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Rose-Victor-Hugo.jpg"];

exportIm = 
  Panel[
    Style[
      Grid[
        {{m, SpanFromLeft}, 
         {TextCell[
            Row[{"balabalaablabalb balabalbalbalba"}], 
            TextJustification -> 1, Hyphenation -> False], 
           SpanFromLeft}, 
         {}, 
         {"Notes: "}, 
         {SpanFromLeft, 
          Item[BarcodeImage["123456789", "QR", 7], Alignment -> Right]}}, 
        Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, True, True, False}, {False}}, 
        BaseStyle -> ImageSizeMultipliers -> 1], 
      7, 
      FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Background -> Gray], 
    Background -> Gray,
    ImageSize -> {210, 297}*2]
```

When you execute this code, you should get this:

[image]

I would like to export it to Word. Is this somehow possible?

My goal is to be able to type text within the section, where it says "Notes: ".

Comment: Export as pdf and, in Windows systems, _Open With_  Word?

Comment: @kglr I tried that, but I cannot write in the section "Notes" because word sees it as an image, and not as blank space.

Comment: Do you want word specifically, or do you want to be able to edit the text? Adobe has great products for editing pdf's

Comment: @Ruud3.1415 I will generate a huge collection of those, and I would like to be able to enter text in the section "Notes" without having to add a textblock or annotation tool afterwards. Ideally, I could open it as html or word and immediately without any adjustment write something in that section.